# Ubuntu 18.04 Wayland second monitor black

Tags: nvidia, wayland, gpu-driver

In Ubuntu 18.04 Wayland with both xorg and nvidia driver I am experiencing the following error when I plug in external monitor.

/var/log/syslog:

```
Feb 21 11:11:28 m org.gnome.Shell.desktop[27286]: [28075:28075:0221/111128.935412:ERROR:edid_parser.cc(102)] Too short EDID data: manufacturer id
Feb 21 11:11:28 m org.gnome.Shell.desktop[27286]: [28075:28075:0221/111128.935537:ERROR:edid_parser.cc(102)] Too short EDID data: manufacturer id
Feb 21 11:11:28 m org.gnome.Shell.desktop[27286]: [28075:28075:0221/111128.935609:ERROR:edid_parser.cc(102)] Too short EDID data: manufacturer id
Feb 21 11:11:29 m gnome-shell[27286]: Failed to blit shared framebuffer: EGL failed to allocate resources for the requested operation.
Feb 21 11:11:29 m gnome-shell[27286]: Failed to set CRTC mode 1920x1080: No such file or directory
Feb 21 11:11:29 m gnome-shell[27286]: Failed to set CRTC mode 1920x1080: No such file or directory
Feb 21 11:11:29 m org.gnome.Shell.desktop[27286]: [28075:28075:0221/111129.100676:ERROR:edid_parser.cc(102)] Too short EDID data: manufacturer id
Feb 21 11:11:29 m org.gnome.Shell.desktop[27286]: [28075:28075:0221/111129.100853:ERROR:edid_parser.cc(102)] Too short EDID data: manufacturer id
Feb 21 11:11:29 m org.gnome.Shell.desktop[27286]: [28075:28075:0221/111129.100969:ERROR:edid_parser.cc(102)] Too short EDID data: manufacturer id
Feb 21 11:11:29 m gnome-shell[27286]: Failed to blit shared framebuffer: EGL failed to allocate resources for the requested operation.
Feb 21 11:11:29 m gnome-shell[27286]: Failed to set CRTC mode 1920x1080: No such file or directory
Feb 21 11:11:29 m org.gnome.Shell.desktop[27286]: [28075:28075:0221/111129.157260:ERROR:edid_parser.cc(102)] Too short EDID data: manufacturer id
Feb 21 11:11:29 m org.gnome.Shell.desktop[27286]: [28075:28075:0221/111129.157473:ERROR:edid_parser.cc(102)] Too short EDID data: manufacturer id
Feb 21 11:11:29 m org.gnome.Shell.desktop[27286]: [28075:28075:0221/111129.157588:ERROR:edid_parser.cc(102)] Too short EDID data: manufacturer id
Feb 21 11:11:29 m gnome-shell[27286]: Failed to blit shared framebuffer: EGL failed to allocate resources for the requested operation.
Feb 21 11:11:29 m gnome-shell[27286]: Failed to set CRTC mode 1920x1080: No such file or directory
Feb 21 11:11:29 m org.gnome.Shell.desktop[27286]: [28075:28075:0221/111129.175038:ERROR:edid_parser.cc(102)] Too short EDID data: manufacturer id
Feb 21 11:11:29 m org.gnome.Shell.desktop[27286]: [28075:28075:0221/111129.175232:ERROR:edid_parser.cc(102)] Too short EDID data: manufacturer id
Feb 21 11:11:29 m org.gnome.Shell.desktop[27286]: [28075:28075:0221/111129.175361:ERROR:edid_parser.cc(102)] Too short EDID data: manufacturer id
Feb 21 11:11:29 m gnome-shell[27286]: Failed to blit shared framebuffer: EGL failed to allocate resources for the requested operation.
Feb 21 11:11:29 m gnome-shell[27286]: Failed to set CRTC mode 1920x1080: No such file or directory
Feb 21 11:11:29 m gnome-shell[27286]: Failed to blit shared framebuffer: EGL failed to allocate resources for the requested operation.
Feb 21 11:11:29 m gnome-shell[27286]: Failed to set CRTC mode 1920x1080: No such file or directory
Feb 21 11:11:31 m gnome-shell[27286]: Failed to blit shared framebuffer: EGL failed to allocate resources for the requested operation.
Feb 21 11:11:31 m gnome-shell[27286]: Failed to set CRTC mode 1920x1080: No such file or directory
Feb 21 11:11:31 m gnome-shell[27286]: Failed to blit shared framebuffer: EGL failed to allocate resources for the requested operation.
Feb 21 11:11:31 m gnome-shell[27286]: Failed to set CRTC mode 1920x1080: No such file or directory
Feb 21 11:11:37 m gnome-shell[27286]: Failed to blit shared framebuffer: EGL failed to allocate resources for the requested operation.
Feb 21 11:11:37 m gnome-shell[27286]: Failed to set CRTC mode 1920x1080: No such file or directory
Feb 21 11:11:44 m gnome-shell[27286]: Failed to blit shared framebuffer: EGL failed to allocate resources for the requested operation.
Feb 21 11:11:44 m gnome-shell[27286]: Failed to set CRTC mode 1920x1080: No such file or directory
Feb 21 11:11:44 m gnome-shell[27286]: Failed to blit shared framebuffer: EGL failed to allocate resources for the requested operation.
Feb 21 11:11:44 m gnome-shell[27286]: Failed to set CRTC mode 1920x1080: No such file or directory
Feb 21 11:11:44 m gnome-shell[27286]: Failed to blit shared framebuffer: EGL failed to allocate resources for the requested operation.
Feb 21 11:11:44 m gnome-shell[27286]: Failed to set CRTC mode 1920x1080: No such file or directory
Feb 21 11:11:44 m gnome-shell[27286]: Failed to blit shared framebuffer: EGL failed to allocate resources for the requested operation.
Feb 21 11:11:44 m gnome-shell[27286]: Failed to set CRTC mode 1920x1080: No such file or directory
Feb 21 11:11:49 m gnome-shell[27286]: Failed to blit shared framebuffer: EGL failed to allocate resources for the requested operation.
Feb 21 11:11:49 m gnome-shell[27286]: Failed to set CRTC mode 1920x1080: No such file or directory
Feb 21 11:11:49 m gnome-shell[27286]: Failed to blit shared framebuffer: EGL failed to allocate resources for the requested operation.
Feb 21 11:11:49 m gnome-shell[27286]: Failed to set CRTC mode 1920x1080: No such file or directory
Feb 21 11:11:49 m gnome-shell[27286]: Failed to blit shared framebuffer: EGL failed to allocate resources for the requested operation.
Feb 21 11:11:49 m gnome-shell[27286]: Failed to set CRTC mode 1920x1080: No such file or directory
Feb 21 11:11:51 m gnome-shell[27286]: Failed to blit shared framebuffer: EGL failed to allocate resources for the requested operation.
Feb 21 11:11:51 m gnome-shell[27286]: Failed to set CRTC mode 1920x1080: No such file or directory
```

Xrandr output:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 1100, maximum 8192 x 8192
XWAYLAND1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 340mm x 190mm
   1920x1080     59.96*+
XWAYLAND5 connected 1920x1080+1920+20 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 510mm x 290mm
   1920x1080     49.93*+
```

What is to be done to make my monitor work?

Comment: Ubuntu uses weston, take a look at [this](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/weston.1.html). It may be of use.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there's a gnome shell extension that is used specifically when dealing with multiple monitors. I've personally never had this problem. It's almost always plug and play with my PC. Search the [gnome extension marketplace.](https://extensions.gnome.org)

Also this seems to be a problem I have noticed on several systems with nvidia being a common factor. I believe this problem is remedied i Ubuntu 19.10 and the upcoming 20.04 release.